# Write a object with ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java, objectoutputstream

It is clear that I can't write the Test object to the file Test.dat, my question is what exactly is the reason that it will not succeed?

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test {

    private int a = 10;
    private double b = 7.5;
    private String m = "valu";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();

        ObjectOutputStream output = ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Test.dat"));
        output.writeObject(t);
        output.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: what error your getting?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method ObjectOutputStream(FileOutputStream) is undefined for the type Test

 at hst17.Test.main(Test.java:15)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from `new` key word, you forgot to implement **Serializable**

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Test implements Serializable{

    private int a = 10;
    private double b = 7.5;
    private String m = "valu";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Test t = new Test();

        ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Test.dat"));
        output.writeObject(t);
        output.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Test.dat"));
```

You had missed the "new" so the compiler is looking for a static method rather than the constructor

Comment: great, thank you very much.
It works when I add a FileNotFoundException, IOException 
and the new ObjectOutputStream.

Comment: Please accept an answer if someone has answered it correctly. In this case Ramesh put a bit more effort in so I won't be offended if you choose his ;-)